# SysV Semaphore Removal

Tags: c, semaphore

Is it possible to determine if a process is the only one currently utilizing a SysV semaphore and then somehow "lock" the semaphore so that the process may safely remove it before another process requests access again?

Comment: I think you need a countdown Latch for that, not a semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your questions. Please feel free to edit (or comment) my answer if I am not accurate enough.

---

First of all, a semaphore is roughly a simple integer value. When a process wants to use it through the `semop()` function, it has 3 possible goals :

- Increase its value (meaning it releases or adds resources to the semaphore)
- Decrease its value (meaning it grabs or removes some resources from the semaphore)
- Wait for the semaphore to take the value 0

The semaphore itself does not hold any information about the processes that might be using it at a given time.

Then, there is no way to make a system-wide "lock" mechanism :

According to the `semop()` man page, all the privileged processes (granted with the capability `CAP_IPC_OWNER`) can run operations on a semaphore set.
Moreover, all the `semctl()` commands are available to a privileged process (including `IPC_RMID`).

This means your code must be prepared to such exotic cases and has to handle the resulting errors. For instance, it is possible to remove immediately the semaphore set at anytime by running the `ipcrm -s <sem_id here>` command as a privileged user.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a;



  if((a = semget(IPC_PRIVATE,1,0777|IPC_CREAT))==-1) {              // get semaphore a
           perror("\nFailed to create semaphore.");
           exit(0);
   }

   if((semctl(a,0,IPC_RMID,0))==-1) {                                // Return semaphore a 
           perror("\nCan't RPC_RMID.");                                             
           exit(0);                                                                                
    }
```